# Show that the OR of n variables cannot be expressed as a polynomial over Fp of degree less than n

Tags: complexity-theory, circuits, polynomials

Here is a question from Computational Complexity by Arora and Barak:

> Show that representing OR of $n$ variables $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ exactly over a polynomial in $GF(q)$ requires degree exactly $n$.
> (This is Exercise 6 in the chapter on circuit lower bounds.)

How do I approach this problem?

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you tried the case $n=2$?  $n=3$?  We discourage questions that are just the statement of an exercise-style task and a request for us to solve it.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3859524/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/131041/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: Yes, my approach actually is convert the domain for $\{0,1\}^n->\{-1,1\}^n$ by taking $y=1-2x, x \in \{0,1\}^n$. Thus all the polynomials can be represented as multinomials. But the arithmetization of OR gives us a n degree multinomial directly, and we are asking whether there is another multinomial of less degree computing OR. This is where I am stuck. Also the transformation we are doing here does not change the degree.

Comment: You've restated the problem.  I suggest that you try to prove it for $n=2$ first, and see how much progress you can make.

Comment: Here is what I have thought. I tried to approach for AND. For n=2, lets suppose we have a degree 1 polynomial computing AND. If we take the monomials containing $x_1$, and take $x_1=0$, we get the result zero. So, the other monomials in which $x_1$ is not present will be zero automatically. Similar with $x_1$, so we can conclude $x_1,x_2$ are present in the same monomial. But that makes its degree 2. Now, if we consider OR circuit of degree 1 and convert to AND by negating the variables, we get a contradiction as negating variable wont change degree. But this is not very formal only intuitive

Comment: @DiptajitRoy your approach works perfectly for any $n$. At what point do you have trouble formalizing?

Comment: @DiptajitRoy please note that I had to correct my answer. You have to choose the summands in increasing order for my prove to work. (I already edited it)

Comment: Yes, I also thought that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $AND:\{0,1\}^n\mapsto\{0,1\}$ be a polynomial in $GF(q), q\geq 2$.
Notice that the polynomial can't have a constant term (the constant term is zero), because
$AND(0,...,0) = 0$.
Meaning we can write the polynomial as:
$$AND(x_1,...,x_n) = \sum_{S\subseteq[1,n], S\neq \emptyset}a_S\prod_{j\in S}x_j$$
We now claim that every non-zero summand in $AND$ contains $x_i$.
Suppose that there are a set of summands not containing $x_i$. Choose the smallest (by amount of different parameters contained) of them. Notice that this  term is uniquely identified by a set $U \subset [1,n]\backslash\{i\}$. Now set $x_u = 1, u\in U$ and $x_v = 0, v\notin U$ and that there is no proper subsets of $U$ whose associated term is non-zero, because $|U|$ was chosen to be minimal.
$$AND(x_1,...,x_n) = a_U$$
This implies $a_U = 0$, because $i\notin U \land x_i = 0$. Repeat for all other summands (in increasing order by size). Thus all non-zero terms contain $x_i$. This applies to all $i\in[1,n]$, hence the degree of $AND$ is $n$.

We can denote $OR$ as $OR(x_1,...,x_n) = 1-AND(1-x_1,...,1-x_n)$ and likewise $AND(x_1,...,x_n) = 1-OR(1-x_1,...,1-x_n)$ by De Morgan's Law. Thus $AND$ and $OR$ must have the same degree.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f\colon \{0,1\}^n \to \mathit{GF}(q)$. Then
$$
f(x) = \sum_{y \in \{0,1\}^n} f(y) \prod_{i\colon y_i=0} (1-x_i) \prod_{i\colon y_i=1} x_i.
$$
This shows that any function from $\{0,1\}^n$ to $\mathit{GF}(q)$ can be represented as a multilinear polynomial.

Now let us show that the representation is unique. This follows from dimension considerations (the space of all such functions has dimension $2^n$, which coincides with the dimension of the space of multilinear polynomials), but we can also prove it directly. If some function has two different representations $P,Q$, then $P-Q$ is a non-zero multilinear polynomial that vanishes on $\{0,1\}^n$. Let $m$ be a monomial in $P-Q$ of minimal degree, appearing with coefficient $c \neq 0$, and let $y \in \{0,1\}^n$ be the point defined as follows: $y_i = 1$ if $x_i$ appears in $m$, and $y_i = 0$ otherwise. Then $(P-Q)(y) = cm(y) = c \neq 0$, contradiction.

Suppose that $P$ is a polynomial representing the OR function. If $P$ is not multilinear, we can replace every occurrence of $x_i^d$ for $d \geq 1$ with $x_i$, obtaining another representation $Q$ of OR whose degree is at most the degree of $P$. According to the above, this representation is unique, and so it must be the following:
$$
Q(x) = 1-\prod_{i=1}^n (1-x_i).
$$
Thus $\deg(P) \geq \deg(Q) = n$.